# Clear only part of the screen in Python

Tags: python, tui

So basically I'm trying to create a text based user interface for a python application. This is what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from blessed import Terminal
import sqlite3
import sys
import os

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")

db = sqlite3.connect('/Users/JoaoPedro/Desktop/PyTest/Alunos')
c = db.cursor()

term = Terminal()

os.system('clear')

def main (self):

print (term.yellow("  CICS   000009/1           Centro Educacional Charles Darwin                 z\OS 3.2   "))
print (term.yellow("  TERMINAL: 2297              Sistema de Controle de Notas                  VITÓRIA/ES   "))
print (term.yellow(" ======================================================================================= "))
print (term.move_y(28)) + (term.yellow(" ======================================================================================= "))
matricula = raw_input (term.move(4, 7) + "Matrícula: ")

os.system('clear')

print (term.yellow("  CICS   000009/1           Centro Educacional Charles Darwin                 z\OS 3.2   "))
print (term.yellow("  TERMINAL: 2297              Sistema de Controle de Notas                  VITÓRIA/ES   "))
print (term.yellow(" ======================================================================================= "))
print
print (term.cyan("       Matrícula    Nome                              Série   Turma      Nota "))

if matricula in ["/", ""]:

    c.execute('select * from A ORDER BY nome')
    rows = c.fetchall()

else:

    c.execute('select * from A WHERE matricula = ?', (matricula,))
    rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print (term.white((term.move_x(9)) + row[0] + (term.move_x(20)) + row[1] + (term.move_x(56)) + row[2] + (term.move_x(64)) + row[3] + (term.move_x(73)) + row[4]))
print (term.move_y(28)) + (term.yellow(" ======================================================================================= "))
command = raw_input (term.move(27, 2) + "Comando ===> ")
if command == "X":
    os.system('clear')
    sys.exit()
else:
    os.system('clear')
    main('self')


main('self')
```

As you can see, I have to print the top and the bottom part every time a new query happens. Now, this works just fine for a small application like this, but if I add more functions to it, I'll have to repeat the same line of code (top and bottom) every time.

I was wondering if it there is any way to keep the top and bottom static and only allow the program to clear the areas in between...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with blessed but given the problem of:

> I'll have to repeat the same line of code (top and bottom) every time.

If you find yourself repeating the same lines of code, use a function.

Put this above "def main (self):"

```
def drawTop():
    print (term.yellow("  CICS   000009/1           Centro Educacional Charles Darwin                 z\OS 3.2   "))
    print (term.yellow("  TERMINAL: 2297              Sistema de Controle de Notas                  VITÓRIA/ES   "))
    print (term.yellow(" ======================================================================================= "))
```

and replace each occurence of the three print lines with

```
drawTop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `os.system('clear')`, just write space characters in the lines of the screen that you want to clear.  Alternatively, just write the new content, with spaces to pad to the end of the line to clear anything that was there before.

Comment: Wow! That is actually pretty good and I would've never thought about that lol